# Covariance of 3 variables

Tags: probability, covariance

$\newcommand{Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}X,Y,Z$ are three random variables each with mean $0$ and variance $20$. $\Cov(X,Y)=\Cov(X,Z)=10$ and $\Cov(Y,Z)=5$. What is $\Cov(3X+Z,3X+Y)$?

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: I have no idea how to go about a 3 random variable covariance.

Comment: Did you look up the formulas on Wikipedia regarding covariance of linear combinations of random variables?

Comment: Yes, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$Covariance behaves like multiplication in that it distributes over linear combinations of random variables. Thus
$$\Cov(3X+Z,3X+Y)=9\Cov(X,X)+3\Cov(X,Y)+3\Cov(X,Z)+\Cov(Y,Z)=9\operatorname{Var}(X)+3\cdot10+3\cdot10+5=180+30+30+5=245$$